# How to open/switch to a process in task manager

Tags: process, vb6, taskmanager

I tried google-ing it but the results are only for ending a process... I want to switch from my vb application to another process...

I'm currently using the  AppActivate but the program title name is not unique so I'm getting an error...
Can i use the * sign?

Comment: You could look at this [VB6 recreation of Task Manager](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/TaskList/) from Karl Peterson. There's code in there for listing processes, and for activating them.

Answer (score 0):

AppActivate Statement

Activates an application window.

Syntax

```
AppActivate title[, wait]
```

The AppActivate statement syntax has these named arguments:

Part Description 
title Required. String expression specifying the title in the title bar of the application window you want to activate. **The task ID returned by the Shell function** can be used in place of title to activate an application.

Use WMI to get the PID or the Toolhelper library.

```
  Private Declare Function Process32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
  Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal Handle As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function Process32First Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
 Private Declare Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal th32ProcessID As Long) As Long

 Private Declare Function GetVersionExA Lib "kernel32" _
     (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Integer



  Private Type PROCESSENTRY32
     dwSize As Long
     cntUsage As Long
     th32ProcessID As Long           ' This process
     th32DefaultHeapID As Long
     th32ModuleID As Long            ' Associated exe
     cntThreads As Long
     th32ParentProcessID As Long     ' This process's parent process
     pcPriClassBase As Long          ' Base priority of process threads
     dwFlags As Long
     szExeFile As String * 260 ' MAX_PATH
  End Type

  Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
     dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
     dwMajorVersion As Long
     dwMinorVersion As Long
     dwBuildNumber As Long
     dwPlatformId As Long           '1 = Windows 95 2 = Windows NT
     szCSDVersion As String * 128
  End Type

   Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1024
   Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ = 16
   Private Const MAX_PATH = 260
   Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = &HF0000
   Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
  'STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED Or SYNCHRONIZE Or &HFFF
   Private Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
   Private Const TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS = &H2&
   Private Const hNull = 0
   Private Const GW_CHILD = 5
   Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Sub mnuInsertProcessList_Click()
         Dim f As Long, sname As String, PList As String, Ret As Long
         Dim hSnap As Long, proc As PROCESSENTRY32
         hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0)
         If hSnap = hNull Then Exit Sub
         proc.dwSize = LenB(proc)
         ' Iterate through the processes
         txtNote.SelText = "PID:int" & vbTab & "ParentPID:int" & vbTab & "ExeName:string" & vbCrLf
         f = Process32First(hSnap, proc)
         Do
                sname = StrZToStr(proc.szExeFile)
                txtNote.SelText = proc.th32ProcessID
                txtNote.SelText = vbTab
                txtNote.SelText = proc.th32ParentProcessID
                txtNote.SelText = vbTab
                 txtNote.SelText = sname
                txtNote.SelText = vbCrLf
                f = Process32Next(hSnap, proc)
         Loop While f = 1
        Ret = CloseHandle(hSnap)
        If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox Err.LastDllError
 End Sub
```